# Automatically display all custom fields when creating new post

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have a bunch of custom fields that I have added to a post:

[image]

When I go and create a new post, the custom fields aren't displayed, and I have to add them all one by one:

[image]

Is there a way to make is so that all my custom fields are automatically displayed when I want to create a new post, so that I only have to enter the values for them?

Comment: Very good question IMHO. I would recommend "Carbon Fields" or "Advanced Custom Fields" as a proper work around. I  use Carbon Fields in each and every project of mine (switched from ACF). With native supprt of custom fields I could only imagine a solution with JavaScript..

Comment: Thanks. Will I have to pay for these plugins?

Comment: ACF has a free and a pro version https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/#pricing-table. The free version should do it for you probably (at least for your original question). [CF](https://carbonfields.net/) is only available as free version. While I'm using CF only I would probably recomend ACF if you don't want to go too deep into development with custom fields....

Comment: ACF comes with a really nice WYSIWYG UI - so making custom fields is quite easy and fun!